# disable Save for TFS work item

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

We are using Team Foundation Server 2010\2012 to manage our requirements. Ours is an FDA audited company. Often someone makes changes to a requirement (user story requirement) after it is in the completed state. This is a red flag. 
We have added a state called 'Locked'.

The question is how do I disable the save functionality of work item when a particular criteria is met? It would be good to display a message to the user that the requirement is locked and that saving is disabled.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: How do you use both TFS 2010 & TFS 2012?

Comment: @aclear16...We are currently using TFS 2010. But planning to swtich to 2012 in 4-6 weeks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to add another field which would be populated when the State is set to 'Locked'. Using the combination of 'ProhibitedValues' and 'Allowed Values', the field will be set to contain a valid value when a person from 'Key Master' sets the state to 'Locked'. This value for the field would be invalid for all other users. The invalid value in the field will prevent the ordinary user from saving after it is locked.

I would be happy to provide example, if requested.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some useful samples how to achieve this in the [Team Foundation Server Process Template Customization Guidance from the VS ALM Rangers](http://vsartfsptguide.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @Ewald...I will poke around that.